# Access remote machine's exported variable via ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

So, what I am trying is this:

- In `192.168.1.2` machine, I had set `export name=arun` in `.bash_profile` file of `www` user
- Then is executed `source .bash_profile`.
- From `192.168.1.3` machine, I am trying `ssh www@192.168.1.2 "echo $name"`

This is giving me blank. Is this not supposed to return me `arun`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to escape the variable to be evaluated on the remote shell, not in your local:

```
ssh www@192.168.1.2 ". .bash_profile;echo \$name"
```

Comment: Even this is returning blank.

Comment: Then make sure the bash_profile is sourced: `source .bash_profile`

Comment: This works fine! So, we need to source .bash_profile for each such command that I may run? Is there no way to source once on 192.168.1.2 and use the variables any number of times from ssh?

Comment: Probably yes. Bash profile is sourced only for the interactive logins.

Comment: Cool. Thank you :). Marking as solution.